# wrapping checkbox inside div breaks javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making great progress with my first project, but I've hit a small stumbling block, I've wrapped the contents below inside divs, before doing it when I clicked the checkbox it enabled the dropdown menu, but now that I've wrapped it inside the divs, the checkbox is no longer working, I've been reading up on getbootstrap.com but I've been unable to find a solution, if anyone could guide me in the right direction so I can learn from what mistake(s) I've make that would be much appreciated, many thanks.

```js
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.dropdown').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            var $checkBox = $('.options');
            $checkBox.on('change', function(e) {
                var $select = $(this).prev();
                if (this.checked) {
                    $select.removeAttr('disabled');
                } else {
                    $select.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <input type="checkbox" class="options" id="options">Dropdown
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <select class="dropdown" disabled>
                    <option value="1">Item #1</option>
                    <option value="2">Item #2</option>
                    <option value="3">Item #3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: [`prev()` finds siblings](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)(elements that are directly in the same parent), your select element is no longer a sibling of the checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
var $select = $('.dropdown');
```

instead of prev() because prev gets the previous element in the dom so you need to target your select via it's class or another selector.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <input type="checkbox" class="options" id="options">Dropdown
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <select class="dropdown" disabled>
            <option value="1">Item #1</option>
            <option value="2">Item #2</option>
            <option value="3">Item #3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.dropdown').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        var $checkBox = $('.options');
        $checkBox.on('change', function(e) {
            var $select = $('.dropdown');
            if (this.checked) {
                $select.removeAttr('disabled');
            } else {
                $select.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

`.prev()` [method](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) searches for the predecessor of elements in the DOM.

So, for selecting the dropdown, you should replace `$(this).prev()` by `$('.dropdown')`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.dropdown').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            var $checkBox = $('.options');
            $checkBox.on('change', function(e) {
                var $select = $('.dropdown');
                if (this.checked) {
                    $select.removeAttr('disabled');
                } else {
                    $select.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <input type="checkbox" class="options" id="options">Dropdown
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <select class="dropdown" disabled>
                    <option value="1">Item #1</option>
                    <option value="2">Item #2</option>
                    <option value="3">Item #3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much